# What is the chronological order of the songs of Ayreon's first story?

Tags: chronological-order, ayreon

[Ayreon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayreon) made a series of rock operas that make up a common science fiction and fantasy story. The albums were released in anachronical order, and some of them partially deal with the same events from different perspectives. The compilation album [*Timeline*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_%28Ayreon_album%29) concluded the story with an epilogue, and came with a chronological timeline poster.

[image]

The poster sets a timeline for some major events of the story. However, the vast majority of songs are not on it. What is the complete chronological order of all songs of Ayreon's first story?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the timeline poster, the booklets, and the lyrics of the songs themselves, I have put together a timeline. Many tracks appear more than one time, representing different things. In one case, a single track appears more than one time because of events happening during it.

Below is the timeline with some notes. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxB7AjBZkKMoektpTTdsbW9EQ2s) it is as an XSPF playlist.

---

*Universal Migrator* and *01011001* are intertwined, but the tracks missing from the poster can be filled in without any problems. These *Universal Migrator* tracks represent events as they happen in history.

### Universal Migrator, Part 2: Flight of the Migrator

> 1.01. Chaos
> 1.02. Dawn of a Million Souls
> 1.03. Journey on the Waves of Time
> 1.04. To the Quasar
> 1.05. Into the Black Hole
> 1.06. Through the Wormhole

### The Source

> 1.01. The Day That the World Breaks Down
> 1.02. Sea of Machines
> 1.03. Everybody Dies
> 1.04. Star of Sirrah
> 1.05. All That Was
> 1.06. Run! Apocalypse! Run!
> 1.07. Condemned to Live
> 2.01. Aquatic Race
> 2.02. The Dream Dissolves
> 2.03. Deathcry of a Race
> 2.04. Into the Ocean
> 2.05. Bay of Dreams
> 2.06. Planet Y Is Alive!
> 2.07. The Source Will Flow
> 2.08. Journey to Forever
> 2.09. The Human Compulsion
> 2.10. March of the Machines

### 01011001

> 1.01. Age of Shadows (including We Are Forever)
> 1.02. Comatose
> 1.03. Liquid Eternity
> 1.05. Beneath the Waves: a) Beneath the Waves / b) Face the Facts / c) But a Memory... / d) World Without Walls / e) Reality Bleeds
> 1.06. Newborn Race: a) The Incentive / b) The Vision / c) The Procedure / d) Another Life / e) Newborn Race / f) The Conclusion

### Universal Migrator, Part 2: Flight of the Migrator

> 1.07. Out of the White Hole

### 01011001

> 1.07. Ride the Comet

### Universal Migrator, Part 2: Flight of the Migrator

> 1.08. To the Solar System

### 01011001

*Ride the Comet* is listed here on the poster, but as it seems to represent the extremophiles being sent off I have removed it. It is still included once earlier.

> 2.01. The Fifth Extinction: a) Glimmer of Hope / b) World of Tomorrow Dreams / c) Collision Course / d) From the Ashes / e) Glimmer of Hope (reprise)

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

> 1.10. The First Man on Earth

### 01011001

> 2.02. Waking Dreams

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

This track doesn't appear on the poster, but is dated in the booklet.

> 1.09. And the Druids Turn to Stone

### The Final Experiment

These tracks represent the events as experienced by Ayreon, the monk.

> 1.01. Prologue: a) The Time Telepathy Experiment - b) Overture - c) Ayreon's Quest
> 1.02. Act I "The Dawning": The Awareness: a) Premonition - b) Dreamtime (Words Become a Song) - c) The Awakening
> 1.03. Act I "The Dawning": Eyes of Time: a) Eyes of Time - b) Brainwaves
> 1.04. Act I "The Dawning": The Banishment: a) A New Dawn - b) The Gathering - c) The Accusation - d) The Banishment - e) Oblivion
> 1.05. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Ye Courtyard Minstrel Boy
> 1.06. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Sail Away to Avalon
> 1.07. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Nature's Dance
> 1.08. Act III "Visual Echoes": Computer-Reign (Game Over)
> 1.09. Act III "Visual Echoes": Waracle
> 1.10. Act III "Visual Echoes": Listen to the Waves
> 1.11. Act III "Visual Echoes": Magic Ride
> 1.12. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Merlin's Will
> 1.13. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": The Charm of the Seer
> 1.14. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Swan Song
> 1.15. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Ayreon's Fate: a) Ayreon's Fate - b) Merlin's Prophecy - c) Epilogue

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

Only *Carried by the Wind* appears on the poster, but the other tracks are dated in the booklet.

> 1.08. Carried by the Wind
> 1.07. Temple of the Cat
> 1.06. Dragon on the Sea
> 1.05. The Shooting Company of Captain Frans B. Cocq

### 01011001

> 2.04. Unnatural Selection

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

> 1.04. One Small Step

### The Final Experiment

This track represents the historical event predicted by Ayreon.

> 1.08. Act III "Visual Echoes": Computer-Reign (Game Over)

### 01011001

> 1.04. Connect the Dots
> 1.08. Web of Lies

### The Final Experiment

These tracks represent the CD released by Mr. Lucassen, The Final Experiment.

> 1.01. Prologue: a) The Time Telepathy Experiment - b) Overture - c) Ayreon's Quest
> 1.02. Act I "The Dawning": The Awareness: a) Premonition - b) Dreamtime (Words Become a Song) - c) The Awakening
> 1.03. Act I "The Dawning": Eyes of Time: a) Eyes of Time - b) Brainwaves
> 1.04. Act I "The Dawning": The Banishment: a) A New Dawn - b) The Gathering - c) The Accusation - d) The Banishment - e) Oblivion
> 1.05. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Ye Courtyard Minstrel Boy
> 1.06. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Sail Away to Avalon
> 1.07. Act II "King Arthur's Court": Nature's Dance
> 1.08. Act III "Visual Echoes": Computer-Reign (Game Over)
> 1.09. Act III "Visual Echoes": Waracle
> 1.10. Act III "Visual Echoes": Listen to the Waves
> 1.11. Act III "Visual Echoes": Magic Ride
> 1.12. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Merlin's Will
> 1.13. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": The Charm of the Seer
> 1.14. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Swan Song
> 1.15. Act IV "Merlin's Will and Ayreons Fate": Ayreon's Fate: a) Ayreon's Fate - b) Merlin's Prophecy - c) Epilogue

### Actual Fantasy

> 1.04. Computer Eyes

### Into the Electric Castle

> 1.01. Welcome to the New Dimension
> 1.02. Isis and Osiris: A) Let the Journey Begin - B) The Hall of Isis and Osiris - C) Strange Constellations - D) Reprise
> 1.03. Amazing Flight: A) Amazing Flight in Space - B) Stardance - C) Flying Colours
> 1.04. Time Beyond Time
> 1.05. The Decision Tree (We're Alive)
> 1.06. Tunnel of Light
> 1.07. Across the Rainbow Bridge
> 2.01. The Garden of Emotions: A) In the Garden of Emotions - B) Voices in the Sky - C) The Aggression Factor
> 2.02. Valley of the Queens
> 2.03. The Castle Hall
> 2.04. Tower of Hope
> 2.05. Cosmic Fusion: A) I Soar on the Breeze - B) Death's Grunt - C) The Passing of an Eagle
> 2.06. The Mirror Maze: A) Inside the Mirror Maze - B) Through the Mirror
> 2.07. Evil Devolution
> 2.08. The Two Gates
> 2.09. "Forever" of the Stars
> 2.10. Another Time, Another Space

### 01011001

> 2.03. The Truth Is in Here

### Lost in the New Real

This album is not technically an Ayreon release. However, Mr. L from the preceding track appears and also other concepts from the Ayreon project. According to the booklet, Mr. L wakes up "several centuries" after the 21st century, probably on Earth. This doesn't fit well with the timeline, but if the "several" part is ignored, it could fit here. Otherwise, the album could be ignored.

> 1.01. The New Real
> 1.02. Pink Beatles in a Purple Zeppelin
> 1.03. Parental Procreation Permit
> 1.04. When I'm a Hundred Sixty-Four
> 1.05. E-Police
> 1.06. Don't Switch Me Off
> 1.07. Dr Slumber's Eternity Home
> 1.08. Yellowstone Memorial Day
> 1.09. Where Pigs Fly
> 1.10. Lost in the New Real
> 2.01. Our Imperfect Race
> 2.02. Welcome to the Machine
> 2.03. So Is There No God
> 2.04. Veteran of the Psychic Wars
> 2.05. The Social Recluse
> 2.06. Battle of Evermore
> 2.07. The Space Hotel
> 2.08. Some Other Time
> 2.09. You Have Entered the Reality Zone
> 2.10. I'm the Slime

### Actual Fantasy

> 1.07. Back on Planet Earth

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

> 1.02. My House on Mars

### 01011001

> 2.05. River of Time
> 2.06. E=mc²

### The Final Experiment

> 1.01. Prologue: a) The Time Telepathy Experiment - b) Overture - c) Ayreon's Quest
> 1.09. Act III "Visual Echoes": Waracle

### 01011001

This track cover the entire ending, and as such multiple tracks take place during it. Specifically, *2084* takes place after *Radioactive Grave*, *The Human Equation* takes place after *To the Planet of Red* and *Universal Migrator* takes place during *Spirit on the Wind*.

> 2.07. The Sixth Extinction: a) Echoes on the Wind / b) Radioactive Grave / c) 2085 / d) To the Planet of Red / e) Spirit on the Wind / f) Complete the Circle

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

> 1.03. 2084

### The Human Equation

This album represents Forever playing the Human Equation program in the Dream Sequencer.

> 1.01. Day One: Vigil
> 1.02. Day Two: Isolation
> 1.03. Day Three: Pain
> 1.04. Day Four: Mystery
> 1.05. Day Five: Voices
> 1.06. Day Six: Childhood
> 1.07. Day Seven: Hope
> 1.08. Day Eight: School
> 1.09. Day Nine: Playground
> 1.10. Day Ten: Memories
> 1.11. Day Eleven: Love
> 2.01. [untitled]
> 2.02. [untitled]
> 2.03. [untitled]
> 2.04. [untitled]
> 2.05. [untitled]
> 2.06. [untitled]
> 2.07. [untitled]
> 2.08. [untitled]
> 2.09. [untitled]
> 2.10. [untitled]
> 2.11. [untitled]
> 2.12. Day Twelve: Trauma
> 2.13. Day Thirteen: Sign
> 2.14. Day Fourteen: Pride
> 2.15. Day Fifteen: Betrayal
> 2.16. Day Sixteen: Loser
> 2.17. Day Seventeen: Accident?
> 2.18. Day Eighteen: Realization
> 2.19. Day Nineteen: Disclosure
> 2.20. Day Twenty: Confrontation

### Universal Migrator, Part 1: The Dream Sequencer

This album and the next represents the Mars Colonist playing the Universal Migrator program in the Dream Sequencer.

> 1.01. The Dream Sequencer
> 1.02. My House on Mars
> 1.03. 2084
> 1.04. One Small Step
> 1.05. The Shooting Company of Captain Frans B. Cocq
> 1.06. Dragon on the Sea
> 1.07. Temple of the Cat
> 1.08. Carried by the Wind
> 1.09. And the Druids Turn to Stone
> 1.10. The First Man on Earth
> 1.11. The Dream Sequencer Reprise

### Universal Migrator, Part 2: Flight of the Migrator

> 1.01. Chaos
> 1.02. Dawn of a Million Souls
> 1.03. Journey on the Waves of Time
> 1.04. To the Quasar
> 1.05. Into the Black Hole
> 1.06. Through the Wormhole
> 1.07. Out of the White Hole
> 1.08. To the Solar System
> 1.09. The New Migrator

### 01011001

*Complete the Circle* takes place after *Universal Migrator*, which is why this track is listed twice.

> 2.07. The Sixth Extinction: a) Echoes on the Wind / b) Radioactive Grave / c) 2085 / d) To the Planet of Red / e) Spirit on the Wind / f) Complete the Circle

### Timeline

> 3.11. Epilogue: The Memory Remains

Comment: As of today, we also have a prequel to 01011001 in [The Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Source_(Ayreon_album)). Not sure off-hand how it fits in with the Universal Migrator, but it's possibly/likely *the* first story in the Ayreon universe.

Comment: Adam - you're correct. The new album [The Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Source_(Ayreon_album)). is the prequel to [01011001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/01011001), as it shows the first time the Forever became dependent on machines (known as "The 'Frame") and they escape to Planet Y. The Source ends with the track "March of the Machines", which tells us that TH1, the AI that accompanied the crew, singing about how it plans to advance, grow, and become the next manifestation of The 'Frame. TH1's actions ultimately lead to history repeating itself, and 01011001's first track, "The

Comment: @AdamLear or anyone else who is up for it: I haven't had the time to edit the answer myself, but would welcome anyone to add new material. I've also had the thought that a Spotify playlist would probably be a good addition.

Comment: I just submitted an edit to add The Source to the appropriate spot in the timeline.

Comment: I don't use Spotify much, however I ported Martino Folli's "Ayreon Timeline" Google Play Music playlist to YouTube Music a while back. Martino's playlist referenced this StackExchange question and answer in its description. It seems that the original GPM playlist never got transferred over before GPM shut down, so I believe my playlist is the only survivor on YTM. Here it is: https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5Av2fX5ysNRHwrNw-jdS-Un2cxq-18We&feature=share

Comment: And here's the YouTube Music playlist ported over to Spotify: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4JKzTbqDUDRNpdGY7E5W0V?si=5d8abea8feb54d50

Comment: I should note that my playlists have the album "The Theory of Everything" inserted between "E=mc²" and  "Prologue: a) The Time Telepathy Experiment - b) Overture - c) Ayreon's Quest" based on this: http://i.imgur.com/XfSLelk.png. It makes logical sense to me, although I feel it's suboptimal because the ending of "E=mc²" flows beautifully into "Prologue: a) The Time Telepathy Experiment - b) Overture - c) Ayreon's Quest". I'm open to suggestions / collaboration.

Comment: @ChristopherParker That's great, thanks! The placement of some of the tracks in a linear playlist is definitely sort of arbitrary, so it's only natural that playlists would differ.